# Multi language Support for Email Template

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforcedx, email-template, customlabel

**Requirement:** On custom Lightning component, List fo records with checkboxes and while selecting the checkbox there is a custom button to *Send Reminder* which should open a popup screen with *default predefined message* which could also be editable by end-user before sending an email.

**Current Approach:** Created an email Template, which gets the default message and opens up in the Editable format by using `<lightning:inputRichText>` tag.

**Challenge:** I want that it should be supported for german language as well, if the user language setting is set to German, it should pre-populate the same message in German.

Image of UI for refrence: [image]

Thanks

Comment: are you using Custom Labels?

Comment: Yes, I am using a custom label. But I doubt that the format of the message would be the same as I used in the template. Currently, rest of the translation was managed with the help of custom labels.